Vue checkbox update after text in v-select changed
My code paints all checkboxes in all rows red. But I want it to paints only one checkbox red, in the row where the text was changed.
I tried to connect the id of the  where I changed text in v-select with the id of checkbox...
My part of the code in Template:
<tr v-for="(item, index) in this.destrTestInfo" :key="index">
            <td class="destr_tab">
              <input type="checkbox" :value="item.name" v-model="selectNameDestr" :id="item.id" v-if="item.isCheckboxChecked">
            </td>
...
            <td class="destr_tab">
              <div style="display: flex">

                <v-select
                    style="width: 450px"
                    @update:modelValue="showAddBtn(item)"
                    v-model="item.digital_status_text"
                    :options="this.dictionary"
                    :id="item.id"
                    :reduce="text => text.id"
                    label="text">
                </v-select>

                <CheckIcon
                    v-if="this.isShowAddBtn===true"
                    :id="item.id"
                    style="color: red"
                    @click="addNewStatus(item.id, item.digital_status_text, item.id)">
                </CheckIcon>

...
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

My part of the code in export block, where I put some data:
  mounted() {
    this.destrTestInfo.forEach(item => {
      item.previous_status_text = item.digital_status_text
      item.isCheckboxChecked = false
    })
  },

My methods:
showAddBtn just allows me to put checkbox if text is changed.
addNewStatus makes checkbox = true if it's an id of changed 
    showAddBtn(item){
      if (item.digital_status_text !== item.previous_status_text) {
        this.isShowAddBtn = true
      }
    },
    async addNewStatus(id,status_id,checkboxId) {
      const urlStat = this.$store.state.supervisionURL + "/api/v1//destructive/result/" + id
      await axios.put(urlStat, {
        digital_status: status_id
      })
          .then(response => {
            this.isShowAddBtn = false
            this.destrTestInfo.forEach(item => {
              if (item.id === checkboxId) {
                item.isCheckboxChecked = true
              }
            })
          }).catch(error => {
           
          })
    },

I don't understand what's wrong. Please, help.

style="color: red" is not conditional on anything, so all the checkboxes will be red.  you want to bind an inline style so the style will only apply if some condition is true, and that condition can be applicable to only a single checkbox.

Sorry. It's not about color. I'm a begginer programmer and English is not my native language. So...The correct statement of the problem is that I need the checkbox to appear only in the line of the table where the text in the v-select block was changed. Now I change the text in one line and checkboxes appear in all lines of the table.

ISSUE: this flag this.isShowAddBtn = true in this function showAddBtn
sets the true value for each record. in another word all records depends on this single flag variable.
SOLUTION: you can achieve your desired result by creating an array of true/false values.
in this case:
First
isShowAddBtn = [] // declare an empty array

Then in the mounted add this line
isShowAddBtn.push(false)

in your function showAddBtn make sure to pass index of the v-for from the template
@update:modelValue="showAddBtn(item, index)"

// after that do this
showAddBtn(item,index){
  this.isShowAddBtn[index] = item.digital_status_text !== item.previous_status_text
}

also make sure you update your function addNewStatus with the same scenario we did to the showAddBtn function.
not to forget this is NOT the best way to do it there are other options, but hopefully this might help you. thanks and good luck.

That was really helpfull. Thanks. In addition to my and your code:
 <CheckIcon
     v-if="this.isShowAddBtn[index]"
     style="color: red"
     @click="addNewStatus(item.id, item.digital_status_text, index)">
 </CheckIcon>

and
        async addNewStatus(id,status_id,checkboxId) {
  const urlStat = this.$store.state.supervisionURL + "/api/v1//destructive/result/" + id
  await axios.put(urlStat, {
    digital_status: status_id
  })
      .then(response => {
        this.destrTestInfo.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (index === checkboxId) {
            item.isCheckboxChecked = this.isShowAddBtn[index]
            this.isShowAddBtn[index] = false
          }
        })

